# Open react bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following functiona react component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import MyModal from './components/Modal/Modal';
import "./App.css";

function App() {

    const [state, setState] = useState('');
    const [modal, openModal] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            setState(data);
        });
    }, []);

    const editRow = (id) => {
        openModal(true);
    }


    return (
        <div>

            {state.length <= 0 &&
                <center><h2>Loading...</h2></center>
            }

            {modal &&
                <MyModal show={modal} onHide="false" />
            }

            <button className="edit" onClick={() => editRow(1)}>Edit</button>

            </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Modal-component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

class MyModal extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                        Modal heading
          </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                    <p>
                        Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                        dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
                        ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </p>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default MyModal;
```

When I click on my edit-button, I get this error in the console:

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in Bootstrap(Modal) (at Modal.js:9)
>       in MyModal (at App.js:31)
>       in div (at App.js:24)
>       in App (at src/index.js:11)
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
>   handling behavior. Visit  to learn
>   more about error boundaries. index.js:2178 Error: Invalid hook call.
>   Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
>   This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem. react.development.js:88 Error: Invalid hook call.
>   Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
>   This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here? Can anyone please explain?

EDIT:

It seems like I get the error when I implement the code for the Modal.

This throws the error:

```
class MyModal extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>



            </Modal>

        );
    }
}
```

This does NOT throw the error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
class MyModal extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
       <div>Hey</div>

        );
    }
}

export default MyModal;
```

Comment: your code working well ! i didn't find any error!

Comment: Please help to create a https://stackblitz.com/ example so reproduce the error

Comment: @adel: hm, It don't work for me. Im going try to update everything.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: man your code is working ! i don't know if there is something else affecting your modal try to give  a codesandbox so we can see the error!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your example (and removed some of the code that I wasn't needed for the demo) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bpzwds

Basically, it seems to work. But I had to change the `onHide` prop as it seems to only accept a function (source: the react-bootstrap [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-props)).

What you might want to try is :

1. Remove the superfluous code (your side effect that fetches data).
2. Verify that you used correct versions of `React` and/or `react-bootstrap`.
3. Add a function (or even `undefined`) to your modal `onHide` prop since you pass it down to the `Modal` from `react-bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

I am find solution  who you can see at links [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567247/reactstrap-getting-modal-to-work/56333390#56333390)

**Note** some time modal don't show because hi have fade setting on false like is next code

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} fade={this.state.fade }  toggle={this.toggle}>
```

How you can see on links up there. 
But on the next links I was get and description at my Serb [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@miotra/upotreba-reactstrap-modala-u-react-apliakcijama-b590822acf2f?fbclid=IwAR0EBmReBagV2OcYr8orvsmLAkICyP6tc-UJMeA5FXx3FiNJgiciFo4am70)